# How to compute the average in modular arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, average

Let's say I'm working in modulo 10 and I have some numbers: 0,0,1,1,9.

How can I calculate the average?

I'm expecting 0,2 in my example (0+0+1+1-1 over 5).

Comment: There isn't a really solid notion of "average" for modular arithmetic, in the sense that you'd like. For instance, mod 10, you might want to say that the average of $5$ and $5$ is zero, because $5 + 5 = 0 \bmod 10$, and dividing by $2$ you still get $0$. That's so clearly wrong that you should probably just abandon all hope.

Comment: @JohnHughes
But I can still, intuitively calculate it, as in my example. If you draw the numbers around a circle, you can "see" the average.
Or I can see on many apps the average hour I woke up (and hours are modular arithmetic)

Comment: The notion of drawing them in a circle would put the "average" inside the circle.  Since it is not on the circle, it does not convey the properties we expect for a "typical value" as used in statistics.

Comment: @timendum in such an event, I strongly suspect that the apps you are referring to are computing the average as a usual average, not as a "modular average", whatever that means.  I suppose you could attempt to define the intuitive concept of modular averages, but you run into challenges quickly such as there being multiple results.  For example, what is the "average" of $0$ and $5$ to you when considered modulo 10?  $2.5$?  Or $7.5$?

Comment: @timendum That works because in reality the hour you wake up will be a value limited to say 4-11 AM. If you go live in a dark cave without light, your daily wake/sleep rythm will change and then your waking our might actually move around the 24h day, with no meanigfull average.

Comment: "Or I can see on many apps the average hour I woke up (and hours are modular arithmetic)"  Whoa!  Not really.  It's assumed you aren't going to wake up at 7am one day and 9pm then next. And we'll not need to calculate "is 9pm 14 hours after 7 or 10 hours before 7".  If you never assume you vary more than 11 hours from the average modulus arithmetic has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The comments and answers here tell you that asked in this generality there is no good answer to your question. If there's a particular context in which you think you need an answer, please [edit] the question to tell us about that context. Then we will know why this question is important to you and may be able to help.

Comment: You mention you can see the average by drawing it in a circle. Why not do that? Find the average in this 2D space and then project out the value onto the ring and then you won't have the problem @hardmath mentioned.

Comment: Not OP but one potential context for this is a circular chromosome--you want the "average position" of some genomic feature. See my comment on the accepted answer below for how I would do this.

Comment: Sorry for the necromancy here, but I think I have a "good" way of establishing modular average that does rely on projecting the points onto a circle. It also gives you distance from origin which can be kind of a "confidence" measure. https://github.com/BWStearns/circadian_tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can attempt to define your intuitive "modular average" in the following way.

Let our set of data points be $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$

We define a modular average of the data points to be a point $\bar{a}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n d(a_i,\bar{a})$ is minimized where the summation here is not done using modular arithmetic, but rather normal arithmetic and $d$ here is a distance function where $d(a,b) = \min\limits_{x\in[a],~y\in[b]}(|x-y|)$ where $[a]$ is the equivalence class of $a$.

We have as an example then, the "modular average" of $\{1,9\}$ in base 10 to be $0$ since this minimizes the sum, giving a sum of $2$ since $d(1,0)+d(9,0)=1+1=2$.  On the other hand, $4$ would not be since you would have $d(1,4)+d(9,4)=3+5=8$.

This is not perfect however as in this play example we would also have every other value "between" $9$ and $1$ also minimizing the sum, for example, $1$ also minimizes the sum as $d(1,1)+d(9,1)=0+2=2$ as well.  This does have the benefit however that an *actual* average will be a modular average.

To account for this, perhaps we might want to look instead at the values of $\bar{a}$ such that instead $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nd(a_i,\bar{a})^2$ is minimized.  In doing so, perhaps we reduce the number of available modular averages, but we lose the property that our usual average will agree with the modular average under several circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best answer for my case.
To minimize the "distance" between the average and the data.

Comment: The sum of the squares is preferable. The sum of distances not only has the problem for the case of 2 points giving equally valid solutions on the interval between them, but also with three points it will clamp to the median point.

Comment: I suggest the following algorithm which does not suffer from the "every value between 9 and 1 minimizes the sum" issue, builds on the answer here, and I think follows the OPs intuitive circular notion of average. Suppose that you have $x_1, x_2,..x_k$ values that you want the average of. Subtract (modulo whatever) $x_1$ from all the values and compute the regular arithmetic average. Then do this for $x_2,$ $x_3$, and so forth. For these $k$ potential averages, choose the one that minimizes the sum of the distances, as above, adding back the $x_i$ at the end.

Comment: Essentially what this is doing is trying out a coordinate system where each of the $x_i$'s is zero and seeing which resulting average is the best (minimizes the distances). Example: find the average of 1, 3, and 8 modulo 10. First iteration: average(0,2,7)=3, sum of the distances=3+1+4=8. Second iteration: average(8,0,6)=4.66, sum of distances = 4.66 + 1.33 + 3.33 = 9.33. Third iteration: average(3,5,0)=2.66, sum of distances = 0.33 + 2.33 + 2.66 = 5.33, this is the winner. Now retranslate 2.66 to the original coordinates by adding what we substracted, 8, this comes to 10.66 mod 10 = 0.66.

Comment: It is true that there are cases where there will not be an unambiguous average. For example, following @JohnHughes's example below, the average of 2 and 8 (mod 12) could just as easily be said to be 5 or 11. So you would need some tiebreaking rule for cases like these. But I think the more points that are in the set, the less likely ties will be (especially if the points aren't restricted to integers).

Answer (score 7):

Let me try to answer this is as principled a way as I can.

Your question suggests that you want to take a list of $k$ numbers, modulo some number $n$, and compute an "average" that's a real number. By "numbers mod $n$", it appear that you mean the numbers $0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1$, i.e., you're not willing to say that $15$ is a number mod $7$. (Most mathematicians are quite happy to say something like this, and informally say "it's the same as the number $1$, mod $7$.")

What property should an "average" have?

Well...

A. if your $k$ numbers are all the same -- say they're all "3"s -- then the average should be that number.

B. What if you add $1$ to all the numbers in your set? Then the average should also increase by $1$, right?

Now right away that presents a problem, because if we're working $\bmod 10$, and we have the list $[9,9,9]$, whose average (by rule A) should be $9$, then we add $1$ to all of them to get $[0,0,0]$, but when we add one to the average, we get $10$. That's kind of a problem. Maybe we should modify rule B to say that the average is always a number between 0 and 9, and if it goes outside that range, we'll just apply the "mod" operation. That makes rule B work OK.

What if we have two sets of $k$ numbers, with averages $a$ and $b$. If we combine them to get a set of $2k$ numbers, we'd expect the average to be $\frac{a+b}{2}$, right? Maybe that should be rule C.

If you keep writing down "reasonable" things, you pretty rapidly find that they're not internally consistent, although you may have to be a bit clever about it, and try to think of examples where computing an average would be difficult, as a guide to showing that your rules are contradictory. Of course, when you find a contradiction, you might say "Wait...rule F wasn't really all *that* important, and it was the one that caused trouble, so I'll just delete it." You can go that route, but at some point you'll find that you're just defining a function, not an average in any reasonable sense.

But let me briefly go with the idea you mention: you can compute it geometrically. That's correct (almost). You can treat the number $k$, $\bmod n$, as being the same as the point 
$$
P_k = (\cos \frac{2 \pi k}{n}, \sin \frac{2 \pi k}{n})
$$
that's a fraction $k/n$ of the way around the unit circle from the point $P_0 = (1,0)$ on the $x$-axis.  To compute the average of a bunch of mod-$n$ numbers, you average the corresponding points in $\Bbb R^2$. The problem is that you end up with...a point in $\Bbb R^2$ rather than a number. But you could imagine taking a ray from the origin through your point and seeing where it hits the unit circle. So if the average came out to be $(0.534, 0)$, then your answer would be the point $(1, 0)$ on the unit circle, which corresponds to $k = 0$. You could do that in general...**except** for cases like mod 12 arithmetic, where the average of 11, 1, 5, and 6 turns out to be at the origin. Now you **can't** project out to the circle.

So while this approach is sort of OK, you have to live with the idea that it may sometimes generate a "no answer" kind of result.

There's a bunch of work on topics like this; I think von Mises may be the name associated with early work on circular averages and statistics on the circle in general. Sam Bass wrote an article for the ACM Transactions on Graphics sometime in the 1990s, I think, about taking averages on higher-dimensional spheres. It would have back-pointers to earlier works.

Finally, your "average time I woke up" idea is also a good one, but if you woke up at 11, 1, 5, and 6, you'd be hard-pressed to find an "average time." What makes that work is that all the times you woke up were reasonably close to 8 AM, so a kind of local averaging works. What's going on, in more sophisticated terms, is that the exponential map from the tangent space at 8 AM to the circle (or in simpler words, the "wrapping function" based at "8" on the clock) lets you pull all the wake-up times into a line. [practically speaking: you take the signed distance from the wake up time to 8:00, so that 8:05 gets sent to 5, and 7:52 gets sent to -8, etc.] You can then take an average in this line, and it turns out (perhaps) that the average is actually 0...so you say your average wake-up time was 8:00. If the average came out to $+3$, you might try the whole exercise again, based at 8:03, and then the average would be zero, and you'd be happy. (This "repeat until average is zero" isn't essential on the circle, because its intrinsic curvature is zero, but if you want to generalize to things like a sphere, it's essential, so I included it.)

But let me note that if we took the times 1:45, 2:01, 2:15, 1:59 (whose average is obviously 2:00) and performed the exercise in the previous paragraph using, as our starting point, the time 8:00, we'd get offsets of 5:45, 6:59, -5:45, and -5:59, which average to 0, so I could claim that 8:00 was your average wake-up time.

Typical responses are "well, you should choose something *reasonable* as your starting point!" or "Oh, that's just a stupid bit of bad luck...we can ignore that." The first answer really is the better one...but what would be a "reasonable" choice? One of the points in the set? That doesn't (generally) work, as you can see by having wake-up times of 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,8,2,2,2,2,2. Perhaps the right starting point is the average! Oh...that's no good. That's what we're trying to FIND. Maybe choose multiple starting points at random, and see what we converge to, and take a vote. (In my example, almost all will result in "2" as the wake up time, and at most one will give the answer "8") But what if the vote is a tie? What if *every* starting point for the wake up times results in the answer that IT is the average? (You can see this happen by having wake up times of 1, 5, and 9.)

As I said, there's basically no good answer...unless you're willing to put some constraint on your points. If, for instance, you're willing to ask for the average *only* for lists of points that all lie in some half-circle, then you can do just fine. (In that case the "exponential" approach works great.) And that's the case with your wake-up times --  they're all within in a few hours, plus or minus, of 8 AM. If if they're all over the clock and the app gives some stupid answer, the app developers don't care --- they lose one user whose behavior is weird enough that they can't send him "buy a latte at Starbucks near you" ads just when he wakes up, i.e., he was a losing customer anyhow. (Call me cynical...)

The discussion I've given here also applies to higher-dimensional spheres, only moreso -- it's not even obvious at first that the exponential method converges, even when all the starting points lie in some hemisphere.

That's a long answer to a short question, and I hope it's of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

The residues of modular arithmetic do not have an order, so there isn't a notion of [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) available.  The arithmetic *mean* (the usual "average") can be calculated when the number to divide by (count of observations) is *coprime* to the modular base (but here you have $5$ observations, which is not coprime to $10$), but it doesn't convey the statistical sense of a *typical* value.

The most useful "average" here is the *mode*, the most frequent value appearing in the observations.  You can sensibly claim that if $1$ appears three times in your sample of five, then $1$ is the mode of your observations.  But here zero appears twice and one appears twice, so there is no unique mode.

Comment: Using the mode presents the same problem if you have a tie. In that case your mode is traditionally the average of the two so becomes a circular argument ;P
E.g. 5 1s and 5 9s would give a mode of 5.